# Statement Coverage Question : ISTQB Foundation Level

Tags: techniques, istqb, flow-charts

I have seen the following question in an ISTQB - Foundation Level sample paper.

Q. 12: If the pseudo code below were a programming language ,how many tests are
required to achieve 100% statement coverage?

1. If x=3 then
2. Display_messageX;
3. If y=2 then
4. Display_messageY;
5. Else
6. Display_messageZ;
7. Else
8. Display_messageZ;

Answers
A. 1
B. 2
C. 3
D. 4

I believe that the **answer is 2** because you can cover all the Statements by covering the following paths.

- A,B,C,E,D,G
- A,B,F,G

[image: Flowchart for the question]

However, many web sites (please find a list of sites at the end) say that the **answer is 3**.

I have two questions :

- Is there anything wrong with my flowchart?
- Why is my answer incorrect?

Links to the places where it says that 3 is the correct answer

1. [Fun with Testing](http://vrushali21.blogspot.com/2012/08/decision-coverage-and-branch-coverage.html)
2. [Testing_Manual_Automation](https://testsoftwarefaq.blogspot.com/2013/10/examples-of-statement-branchdecision.html)
3. [Software Testing Cafe](http://softwaretesting-cafe.blogspot.com/2011/04/branch-coveragestatement.html)
4. [FYI Center](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/ISTQB-Software-Testing-Exam/If_the_pseudocode_below_were_a_programming_langu.html)
5. [Patashala.com](http://istqb.patshala.com/Qpapers/testdesignQpaper1.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is there anything wrong with my flowchart?**

Yes and no. It is correct *functionally*: it describes exactly what the code is supposed to do. However, in code, `Display_messageZ` is called in two places (instead of one, as in your chart).

**Why is my answer incorrect?**

Because you follow the chart instead of the code, you miss the second call to `Display_messageZ` to achieve full statement coverage. It's the same statement, but it is still a different line of code so they both need to be executed with this type of coverage.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for this question is 3. Here's why,

There are 2 if statements here. Each if statement has 2 possible out comes. Hence for each if statement 2 test cases would be required.

In the case mentioned above the if statements are nested, i.e., 1 if statement is within another if statement.

So for the first if statement:

Case 1: If condition true, display message x and go inside the nested if statement (continue to Case 3).

Case 2: If condition false, skip nested if statement and display message z.

Case 3:  If nested condition true, display message y.

Case 4: If nested condition false, display message z.

Here, there are 2 different else statements for the nested if statements. So to cover the else condition(statement) of the inner if statement you will need one additional test case which makes it 3 cases in total.

In case of nested if conditions my usual approach is **total cases = number of if statements + 1**

Comment: I guess you talk of the branch/decision/path coverage here. In that case, your answer is correct. To cover all the branches/decisions/paths one needs 3 test cases. However, you can cover all the statements(https://www.istqb.guru/how-to-calculate-statement-branchdecision-and-path-coverage-for-istqb-exam-purpose/) in 2 test cases. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: I updated my answer. I guess that should clarify your doubt.

Comment: Yep, now it is clear

Answer (score 1):

Correct flow chart --

[image]

Answer is C = 3

1. A,B, F,G
2. A,B, C, E, D, F, G
3. A, B,C, E, F, G

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the right chart and you have got 3 paths to cover all statements[image]

Answer (score -1):

Statement 6 and statement 8 will be considered as one. Statement 2 and statement 4 are two separate statement. That's why statement coverage will be 3.